# Enquote vs Textquote

Tags: quotation

I couldn't find direct answer on the internet. Both seem to give identical result, which also includes your current language settings. Are there any differences between them? Overleaf documentation doesn't mention `enquote` at all, which might point out that it's obsolete, but I'm not really sure.

```latex
\enquote{first text} \newline
\textquote{second text}
```

Comment: I guess you are using [package `csquotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes). So please have a look into [the `csquotes` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf), e.g., section 3.1 and section 3.3. If you need more information please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), so we won't need guessing.

Comment: Overleaf not having documentation of some LaTeX-related thing does and can _not_ point out that it is obsolete. Overleaf is a small project for editing LaTeX code, not the entire LaTeX. You probably would not want to sideline the efforts of a lot of friendly developers of enormous LaTeX-packages. If such a judgement is to be made, then the only true and reliable source would be [CTAN](https://ctan.org).